# Will the initial velocity of an object in space get multiplied if a constant acceleration is applied?

Tags: spacecraft, physics, velocity, acceleration

Imagine an object travelling in space in the speed of 60 Kmph which took acceleration x
if accelerated with the same x, will the object travel faster than 60 Kmph or travel in the same speed cuz of same acceleration.

(and yes i skipped my physics class, so pls help me)

Comment: Body of the question seems to be one long, run-on sentence. Please break it up logically into multiple sentences. Please add more details about your question. It is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Acceleration and velocity have both magnitude and direction.  The same magnitude of acceleration applied to the same velocity can change only its speed but not its direction of motion, or only its direction of motion but not its speed, or a combination of both, depending on the difference between the direction of the velocity and the direction of the acceleration.

An object in a idealized perfectly circular orbit is always accelerating (due to gravity, using no fuel), carefully arranged so that it neither speeds up nor slows down, but maintains constant magnitude of both acceleration and velocity.  The directions, however, change because the object moves.  That is, the acceleration always points to the center of the circle, and the velocity always points tangent to the circle, but those vectors rotate in space once per orbit because the object – the place *from which* they point – is moving in a circle.